# “No such file or directory” when comparing numbers in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm getting an strange error.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a number"
read var
declare -i num
num=0
        while ($num<$var)
        do
                echo "$num"
        done
```

./loop: line 5: 6: No such file or directory

What am i mistaking?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax:

```
while [ "$num" -le "$var" ]
do
    echo "$num"
done
```

What you wrote, `$num<$var`, is the syntax for running a program with a file as input. Like this:

```
cat < file.txt
```

The error is telling you that `$var` (the content of `$var`, not literally "var") was not found when Bash attempted to open it as a file.

Comment: Needs more quotes. `[ "$num" -le "$var" ]` -- otherwise you'll have bad behavior in various unusual circumstances. (For instance, if `$var` contained `5 -o 1 -eq 1`, it could return true without being equal to `num` at all.

Comment: to be clear, btw, this is the POSIX-compliant approach -- the answers suggesting `(( ))` are advising use of extensions. (Useful extensions, I think, and ones worth knowing and using, but extensions nonetheless).

Comment: ...also, if *both* `$num` and `$var` were empty, then this would be `[ -le ]`, which is equivalent to `[ -n -le ]`, thus testing whether the string `-le` is empty. Lots of corner cases; better to quote properly and thereby avoid them.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I fixed the quotes. These were good comments :)